# Spring not looking in the Config subfolder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Springboot and I am having trouble with externalizing my properties files.
I have multiple ".properties" files that I have kept in a subdirectory "config/". I have removed context-placeholders from my project and have included the comma-separated properties files while executing the jar.

eg. java -jar myjar.jar --spring.config.location=file:////config/PROP1.properties, file:///config/PROP2.properties -debug

I have few questions

1. Why are the files in the config directory not being read even after explicitly mentioning where to look?
2. I have my own dependencies in the project that have same-named properties files packed in its jar. Is that creating any sort of problem when SpringBoot tries to read the files from the config folder while executing my project jar?

**Update**

Now I am keeping only a single properties file suppose ABC.properties outside the jar in the same directory . I am using the name "ABC" instead of "application". I am using the below command

java -Dserver.log.dir=/path/to/log/dir -jar myjar.jar --server.port=9090 --spring.config.name=ABC --prop1=val1

I have overriden a property in my external property file but I don't see the overriden value being used when I run the application. My new questions are

1. Is there anything wrong with the command-line?
2. I have the following line in xml bean configuration

   <context:property-placeholder location="ABC.properties" />. Is this causing any sort of problems to detect and use the external properties?
3. If the above is true and I have to remove the line how will SpringBoot understand from where the property values are to be imported?
4. *(Not related directly to the question)* Is there a order that I need to follow while giving command line arguments?

Comment: Are you running your app from `/`? If not, I think your location URLs may be wrong.

Comment: That was a typo

Comment: What was a typo? The URLs still look wrong to me after your edit. Both of the current answers explain why.

Comment: The typo was a single '-' in front of spring.config.location. I didn't edit the URLs as those are the ones I did use in my command.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot has explicit indicate how to write this external configuration. See doc ref here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files

Basically, you need to specify the location like this:

1. --spring.config.location=classpath:/somefolder/somefile.properties
2. --spring.config.location=file:./somefolder/somefile.properties

From your command line, it seems that you are missing one dash, and also using a wrong format of file schema.

Comment: So is it that if I don't mention the properties files names explicitly as an argument then they won't be picked up even when they are in the config directory?

Comment: That's correct, the only by default auto-load file name is application-{profile}.properties or application.properties (same as .yaml)

Comment: Please check the update above I have provided an update after following what suggestions I got. My problem is still not resolved?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**: Why are the files in the config directory not being read even after explicitly mentioning where to look?

**A1**: If your config folder is beside your jar file, your command should be like

- `java -jar myjar.jar --spring.config.location=file:./config/PROP1.properties`

meanwhile, you can also use the full path to target your config file.

**Q2**: If I don't mention the properties files names explicitly as an argument then they won't be picked up even when they are in the config directory

**A2**: No. See [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files), Spring Boot will try to find config files from the four places:

- A /config subdir of the current directory.
- The current directory
- A classpath /config package
- The classpath root

If `spring.config.location` is `not` set, files in these folders named `application.properties` will be treated as valid config file. You can change the accepted file name by setting property `spring.config.name`.

**Q3** About Config File Priority

**A3** As described in the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) mentioned earlier, if same name properties appear in different config files, locations higher in the list override lower items.

Another tip, it will be better to remove config files inside the jar file, so you can get a full view of configuration just in one place (the externalized config folder);

Comment: Thanks a lot Lebecca. Can you please check the update above as I have another consequential roadblock in this?

Comment: @PratyayMukherjee It is wired you are using spring boot with xml conf. The `location` attribute seems not correct since it neither start with `file:` nor `classpath:`. Have a try to remove this line from xml conf and test again. Good luck.